# Aligning two labels in a Div

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Using ASP.NET to create a `div` with two labels within it.

I am having issues lining up the labels in the div as I want the first to line up to the left and the second to the right.  The issue I have is I dont know the length of the data the labels display as it is queried from a database so it could change.

Here is my code:

ASP.NET/HTML

```
<div class="results" id="divResult1" runat="server" visible="false">
        <asp:Label ID="lblResult1Desc" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblResults1"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblResult1Val" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblResults2"></asp:Label>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.results {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius:10px;
}

.lblResults1 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #000000;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 10px;

}

.lblResults2 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #000000;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 25px;
    width: 50px;

}
```

The image below shows what I see when the second label (under description B) gets a long value and as you can see it looks a bit messy as it is overlapping the end of the div.  If there is a short value as in description A there is a lot of white space after it.

[image]

Also the descriptions can vary in length (although nothing too long and can easily fit in the space up to the £ sign).

I am not great at CSS so is there  a way to line the descriptions up to the left with a little bit of padding and the values to the right with a little bt of padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.results {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.results::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.result {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #000;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.lblResults1 {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}
.lblResults2 {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: right;
}

.result--ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="results" id="divResult1">
  <label ID="lblResult1Desc" class="result lblResults1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</label>
  <label ID="lblResult1Val" class="result lblResults2">€ 12.735.430,9</label>
</div>

<div class="results" id="divResult1">
  <label ID="lblResult1Desc" class="result lblResults1 result--ellipsis">WITH ELLIPSIS Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</label>
  <label ID="lblResult1Val" class="result lblResults2">€ 12.735.430,9</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add some padding to result class

```
.result {
padding: 10px; /*this will include top and bottom too */
}
```

remove margin left and right from lblResults1 and lblResults2

Answer (score 0):

It's the fixed width on `.lblResults2` that's causing the issue. When your content is wider than the fixed width - showing as `width: 50px;` in your code then it gets "chopped off" and so your padding doesn't take effect. Try removing that width and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a flex layout like this:

```
.results {
height: 30px;
background-color: #ffffff;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 30px;
margin-top: 10px;
border: solid 1px white;
border-radius:10px;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
.lblResults1 
{
font-size: 1.1em;
color: #000000;
}
.lblResults2 {
font-size: 1.1em;
color: #000000;
}
```